# What were Lord Macartney's original words about Chinese under the Qianlong Emperor's brutal regime in 18th century?

Tags: china, british-empire, 18th-century, quotes, qing-dynasty

This is a follow-up question of [Where can I find modern account of Macartney Embassy to China (1792–1794)?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66802/where-can-i-find-modern-account-of-macartney-embassy-to-china-1792-1794)

After Lord Macartney returned from his mission to the Qianlong Emperor, he made a poignant but quite accurate assessment about Chinese had become **semi-barbarian** (I am Chinese and I say these with only admiration for him).

The translated Chinese words “自从北方或满洲鞑靼征服以来，至少在过去150年里，没有改善，没有前进，或者更确切地说反而倒退了；当我们每天都在艺术和科学领域前进时，他们实际上正在变成半野蛮人”

"Since the conquest of the North or the Manchurian Tatars, at least in the past 150 years, there has been no improvement, no advancement, but only backwardness; when we advance in the arts and sciences every day, they are actually becoming semi-barbarian."

BTW, his companion [Sir John Barrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_John_Barrow,_1st_Baronet) made the similar comments in his book "Travel in China", "While they are by nature quiet, passive, and timid, the state of society and the abuse of the laws by which they are governed, have rendered them indifferent, unfeeling, and even cruel"

He only made a small mistake about Manchurians as Tatar (Mongol descent)

But, given my experience with [this other question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66722/did-lord-acton-ever-say-freedom-faces-four-major-challenges), I would like to see his original words.

Another poignant but quite accurate assessment was "中华帝国只是一艘破败、疯狂的战船。如果说已在过去的150年间依旧能够航行，以一种貌似强大的外表威慑邻国，那是因为侥幸出了几位能干的船长"

”The Chinese Empire is just a dilapidated and crazy warship. If it is said that it has been able to sail in the past 150 years and deter neighboring countries with a seemingly powerful appearance, it is because a few capable captains were lucky enough to be able to sail."

I do believe Lord Macartney said those words. Many published books, papers (in Chinese) about the Macartney mission quote those words. So I don't have any doubt, like when I asked "Did Lord Acton ever say freedom faces four major challenges"?

I just like to see his original words. Thanks!

Comment: I believe "Tartary" was synonymous with Manchuria among western geographers at that time. I.e. not an mistake, rather just as correct as calling parts of the Caribbean "West Indies"

Comment: The wp article says "By the seventeenth century, however, largely under the influence of Catholic missionary writings, the word Tartar came to refer to the Manchus and the land they ruled as Tartary"" Which (I hope) is basically what I wrote above.

Comment: And I would argue in Chinese it is not a mistake either if it is a faithful translation of what Macartney wrote.

Comment: It is like arguing that everyone who writes about Tajiks in China is making a mistake because Tajiks speak Persian and Tajiks in China speak languages that are closer to Pashto. It is not a mistake, it is just a different nomenclature.

Comment: Btw 克里米亞韃靼人 are not Mongols either.

Comment: Anyway the usage of "European" nomenclature like 满洲鞑靼 might be a hint that these words are a reasonably close translation from English.

Comment: Don't you see that I have no interest in discussing this here?! If you really want, you can ask a question about that and I will answer to my best knowledge what that word mean in Chinese.

Comment: No need to get impatient. My whole point is that the meaning of that word in Chinese or any other language is irrelevant for deciding whether Macartney made any mistake. What is relevant is the meaning of the word in late 18th century **English**. That meaning is already reasonably well explained in the wikipedia article that you kindly provided at some point and then deleted again. I agree we do not really need to discuss this further. Though if the discussion bothers you so much, you could just edit out the offending sentence.

Comment: As Michael Seifert pointed out in the other chat, the first quote is on page 413 of this book: https://archive.org/stream/someaccountofpub02barr/someaccountofpub02barr_djvu.txt . The second quote is on page 398. If Michael Seifert does not post the quote earlier, I can post it tonight (in about 10 hours from now).

Comment: The book title is "Some account of the public life, and a selection from the unpublished writings, of the Earl of Macartney" by John Barrow. Not sure if Michael Seifert mentioned that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quotes in question can be found in Macartney's *Journal of an Embassy from the King of Great Britain to the Emperor of China*. This journal was later (re?)published in [*Some account of the public life, and a selection from the unpublished writings, of the Earl of Macartney*](https://archive.org/details/someaccountofpub02barr/), Volume 2, which is available via archive.org.

The first quote can be found on p. 412–413.  In this context, Macartney is discussing the attitude of Chinese leaders to the outside world, and hypothesizing that it may stem from the fact that they were more civilized than the rest of the world at one time.

> When  Marco  Polo,  the  Venetian,  visited  China  in  the thirteenth  century,  it  was  about  the  time  of  the  conquest  of China  by  the  western  or  Mongol  Tartars,  with  *Kublai-khan*, a  grandson  of  *Gengis-khan*,  at  their  head.  A  little  before that  period  the  Chinese  had  reached  their  highest  pitch  of civilization;  and  no  doubt  they  were  then  a  very  civilized people  in  comparison  of  their  Tartar  conquerors,  and  their European  contemporaries; **but  not  having  improved  and advanced  forward,  or  having  rather  gone  back,  at  least  for these  hundred  and  fifty  years  past,  since  the  last  conquest by  the  northern  or  Mantchou  Tartars,  whilst  we  have  been every  day  rising  in  arts  and  sciences,  they  are  actually  become a  semi-barbarous  people  in  comparison  with  the  present nations  of  Europe.**  Hence  it  is  that  they  retain  the  vanity, conceit,  and  pretensions  that  are  usually  the  concomitants  of half-knowledge;  and  that,  though  during  their  intercourse with  the  embassy,  they  perceived  many  of  the  advantages we  had  over  them,  they  seemed  rather  surprised  than  mortified, and  sometimes  affected  not  to  see  what  they  could  not avoid  feeling.  In  their  address  to  strangers  they  are  not restrained  by  any  bashfulness  or  *mauvaise honte* [“false modesty”–ed.],  but  present themselves  with  an  easy  confident  air,  as  if  they  considered themselves  the  superiors,  and  that  nothing  in  their  manners or  appearance  could  be  found  defective  or  inaccurate.

The second quote can be found on p. 398.  In this passage, Macartney is discussing the possible consequences of an armed conflict between England and China, and how it would (among other things) disrupt the British economy.  He then notes that internal misfortune in China might also lead to a trade disruption, likening China to a warship.

> But  all  these  inconveniences  and  mischiefs, which  I  have  stated  as  objects  of  apprehension,  may happen  in  the  common  course  of  things  without  any quarrel  or  interference  on  our  part.  **The  empire  of  China is  an  old  crazy  first-rate  man  of  war,  which  a  fortunate succession  of  able  and  vigilant  officers  has  contrived  to keep  afloat  for  these  hundred  and  fifty  years  past;  and  to
> overawe  their  neighbors,  merely  by  her  bulk  and  appearance;**  but  whenever  an  insufficient  man  happens  to  have the  command  upon  deck,  adieu  to  the  discipline  and  safety of  the  ship.  She  may  perhaps  not  sink  outright;  she  may drift  some  time  as  a  wreck,  and  will  then  be  dashed  in  pieces on  the  shore;  but  she  can  never  be  rebuilt  on  the  old bottom.

Note that the word "crazy" in this quote does not mean "insane" as it frequently does today, but instead is an older sense of the word meaning "full of cracks or flaws; damaged, impaired, unsound; liable to break or fall to pieces; frail, 'shaky'" (OED).  Similarly, ["first-rate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-rate) in the context of a warship means a particularly large warship (hat tip to @Jan for pointing this out in the comments.)

Comment: Macartney's vocabulary and phrasing are in something of an older style, so please let me know if any other words in the quotes or phrases above need further explanation.

Comment: Wow, the nuance of these words is quite different from OP's quote.

Comment: That may be because of my translation :$ English is not my native language. But I think the first quote is not that different, the second quote "The empire of China is an old crazy first-rate man of war" I wrote "The Chinese Empire is just a dilapidated and crazy warship". (with google translate's help to use the word dilapidated)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I was bit confused with the "first-rate" used in "old crazy first-rate". If "first-rate" means good, why then old crazy ?

Comment: I check several China translated words for "The empire of China ..."  they all emphasize 破败, i.e. "dilapidated", so I was surprised the original words was ""old crazy first-rate"

Comment: @Qiulang First-rate in this context probably just means "especially large", see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-rate

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗:  I would say that "diladipated" is a reasonable modern substitute for "old and crazy" as Macartney meant it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. BTW, the embassy’s comptroller, John Barrow also made quite some poignant but accurate assessments about then China. Do you happen to know where can I find his book ? I won't ask yet another question for John Barrow, otherwise it will just bother everyone.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗:  Barrow's book *Travels in China* appears to be available for free on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Travels_in_China/klIOAAAAQAAJ) and the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/travelsinchinaco00barr).  Those would be the first places I would look.  I don't know whether these sites are available in China, though.

Comment: Hi I knew it was an old question and I recently found a much better version of Barrow's book Travels in China  here https://www.gutenberg.org/files/28729/28729-h/28729-h.htm